# Jmeter execution error shows i.e. jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Filename must not be null or empty

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to execute the test script and showing the below error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Filename must not be null or empty
```

Total error code is:

```
2016/12/06 19:05:13 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 
2016/12/06 19:05:13 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2016/12/06 19:05:13 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*) 
2016/12/06 19:05:14 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : www.cebsworldwide.com 
2016/12/06 19:05:14 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 5 threads for group www.cebsworldwide.com. 
2016/12/06 19:05:14 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error 
2016/12/06 19:05:14 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 5 ramp-up 1 perThread 200.0 delayedStart=false 
2016/12/06 19:05:14 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: www.cebsworldwide.com 1-1 
2016/12/06 19:05:14 ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Filename must not be null or empty
    at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.reserveFile(FileServer.java:262)
    at org.apache.jmeter.config.CSVDataSet.iterationStart(CSVDataSet.java:178)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterationStart(GenericController.java:405)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterEvents(GenericController.java:397)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:158)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:123)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.AbstractThreadGroup.next(AbstractThreadGroup.java:87)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:247)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Are you using CSV Dataset Config? what is file location? would you share the screen shot of Test Plan?

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs when your add [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to your Test Plan and leave "Filename" input blank:

[image: CSV Data Set Config error]

- If you are not using CSV Data Set Config for parametrization - just delete or disable it and the error should go away
- If you are planning to use data from the CSV file in your script - you need to provide relative or better absolute path to the CSV file and configure other parameters according to your needs. See [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) article for comprehensive information.